# Write 16 bits character to .xlsx file using Apache POI in Java

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, xlsx

I have a problem in Apache POI.
The problem is, I try to put a 16 bits character value (such as CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B) to .xlsx file. However, the cell value become a question mark(like ????) in generated .xlsx file.

Anyone know how to handle the 16 bits character value in Apache POI with .xlsx format???

My POI version is 3.14

Code sample as below:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Test");

XSSFRow row1 = sheet.createRow(0);
XSSFCell r1c1 = row1.createCell(0);
r1c1.setCellValue(""); // value of CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B
XSSFCell r1c2 = row1.createCell(1);

FileOutputStream fos =new FileOutputStream("D:/temp/test.xlsx");
workbook.write(fos);
fos.close();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share some code, which is writing these characters to excel?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. the sample code added.

Comment: Have you made sure that your java compiler is using the right encoding for reading in your source file containing those characters?

Comment: The problem exists. But not with 16 bit (2 byte) UTF-8 characters. It is with characters which needs more than 2 byte in UTF-8 encoding. Not sure who to blame, `apache poi` or `java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream`. In fact the unicode is there in the models until we write it into ZIP.  Example `Cell cell = row.createCell(0);  String emoji = ""; cell.setCellValue(emoji); System.out.println(cell);` here emoji is there but after write there is `??` in `sharedStrings.xml`.

Comment: Hi Gagravarr, I think the problem is not related to Java compiler because this is fine if I changed from .xlsx(xssf) file to .xls file(hssf)

Comment: Hi Axel Richter, then do you have any solutions or alternative solution to put those character to .xlsx?

Comment: Try u-escaped text too `"\u4e03"` (七) - so the java source encoding cannot interfere.

Comment: @Joop Eggen: This will not work for Unified Ideographs Extension since those code points are from U+20000 upwards. http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U20000.pdf And even if it would work, it would also not fit into char.

Comment: @AxelRichter U+20000 == `"\ud840\udc00"` (2 UTF-16 chars) == `new String(new int[] { 0x20000 }, 0, 1)`. However thanks, and indeed there might be a bug concerning two chars: single char processing and such. (My comment however was merely meant to simply exclude the unlikely error, the java compiler using another encoding than the editor.)

Comment: @Joop Eggen: That's a good point, thank you. I had not thought along this. So we could patch `org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver`, it should simply not exclude the high-surrogates range, (\uD800-\uDBFF) and the low-surrogates range (\uDC00-\uDFFF) as bad chars. Will try this afternoon.

Comment: @Joop Eggen, I had tried to put 2 UTF-16 chars instead of the string of Unified Ideographs Extension but the result also the same.

Comment: @leonlai almost to be expected. One could unzip the .xlsx and look into the SharedStrings.xml. But it looks like a bug, though xlsx is simpler than xls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem exists. But not with 16 bit (2 byte) Unicode characters from `0x0000` to  `0xFFFF`. It is with characters which needs more than 2 byte in Unicode encoding. Those are the characters which where mentioned as `Unicode code points` in [Java Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode): "Unicode code point is used for character values in the range between U+0000 and U+10FFFF, and Unicode code unit is used for 16-bit char values that are code units of the UTF-16 encoding." The Java platform uses the UTF-16 representation in char arrays and in the String and StringBuffer classes. In this representation, supplementary characters (Characters whose code points are greater than U+FFFF) are represented as a pair of char values, the first from the high-surrogates range, (\uD800-\uDBFF), the second from the low-surrogates range (\uDC00-\uDFFF).

The problem is with `org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver`.  This works with a `private char[] _buf`. But since `char` max value is `0xFFFF`, Unicode codepoints from `0x10000` to `0x10FFFF` are not possible to store in `char`. So the will be stored as a pair of char values.

There is a method

```
    /**
     * Test if a character is valid in xml character content. See
     * http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml#NT-Char
     */

    private boolean isBadChar ( char ch )
    {
        return ! (
            (ch >= 0x20 && ch <= 0xD7FF ) ||
            (ch >= 0xE000 && ch <= 0xFFFD) ||
            (ch >= 0x10000 && ch <= 0x10FFFF) ||
            (ch == 0x9) || (ch == 0xA) || (ch == 0xD)
            );
    }
```

That code is totally buggy since it checks if a `char` is between `0x10000` and `0x10FFFF`. As mentioned this is not possible at all.

Also it excludes the high-surrogates range, (\uD800-\uDBFF) and the low-surrogates range (\uDC00-\uDFFF) as bad chars. So the code point representations as a pair of char values will be excluded.

So the problem results from a bug in `org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver`.

---

Patch:

Goal: Not exclude the high-surrogates range, (\uD800-\uDBFF), and the low-surrogates range, (\uDC00-\uDFFF), as bad chars. So Unicode code points above U+10000, stored as two 16 bit `chars` will not be excluded in `XML`.

Download [Saver.java](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/xmlbeans/trunk/src/store/org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/store/Saver.java?revision=1025773&view=co). Change the `private boolean isBadChar ( char ch )` to

```
    /**
     * Test if a character is valid in xml character content. See
     * http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml#NT-Char
     */
    private boolean isBadChar ( char ch )
    {
        return ! (
            (ch >= 0x20 && ch <= 0xFFFD ) ||
            (ch == 0x9) || (ch == 0xA) || (ch == 0xD)
            );
    }
```

in both `static final class OptimizedForSpeedSaver` and `static final class TextSaver`.

Compile `Saver.java`.

Store a backup of `xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar` somewhere outside the classpath.

Replace `Saver$OptimizedForSpeedSaver.class` and `Saver$TextSaver.class` in `xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar` -> `/org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/store/` with the new compiiled ones.

Now Unicode code points above U+10000 will be stored in `sharedStrings.xml`.

---

**Disclaimer:**
This is not well tested. So don't use this in productive. It is only shown here to describe the problem. Maybe some programmers on `xmlbeans.apache.org` will find the time to solve the problem with `org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver` properly.

---

**Update**
There is a [xmlbeans-2.6.2.jar](https://maven2repo.com/com.github.pjfanning/xmlbeans/2.6.2/jar) available now. This contains the patch already.

---

**Update**
There is a [xmlbeans-3.0.0.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/3.0.0) available now. This also contains the patch already.

It does:

```
/**
 * Test if a character is valid in xml character content. See
 * http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml#NT-Char
 */
static boolean isBadChar ( char ch )
{
    return ! (
        Character.isHighSurrogate(ch) ||
        Character.isLowSurrogate(ch) ||
        (ch >= 0x20 && ch <= 0xD7FF ) ||
        (ch >= 0xE000 && ch <= 0xFFFD) ||
        (ch >= 0x10000 && ch <= 0x10FFFF) ||
        (ch == 0x9) || (ch == 0xA) || (ch == 0xD)
    );
}
```

So it checks whether `char ch` is `HighSurrogate` or `LowSurrogate` and if so it is not a bad char. OK.

But nevertheless it checks whether `char ch` is greater than or equal `0x10000`. Again: This is not possible for a `char`! The max value of a `char` is `0xFFFF`.

Comment: Hi Axel Ricter. Thanks for your explanation! Is it mean that there is no way to put 16 bits character to .xlsx using POI?

Comment: @leonlai: There is no problem with 16 bit characters. There is a problem with Unicode characters which needs **more** than 16 bit. See my last comment below your question. I will try a patch this evening.

Comment: Hi Axel Ricter.Thanks for your explanation, but how can we solve the problem in org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver?

Comment: sorry that may I ask how to replace those class to xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar? I tried to replace those files but it show the following message: 0 Error: Duplicate filename: 1 org\apache\xmlbeans\xml\stream\Location.class 2 org\apache\xmlbeans\xml\stream\Location.class

Comment: @Alex Ricter: Thanks for your help. That's ok now. I got the xmlbeans source code,updated Saver.java and build the new jar. However, may I ask why this can solve the problem after changed your suggested code?