# Apache POI: Save unicodes to xslx file

Tags: java, apache-poi

How to save symbols like  to xlsx file using Java 8 and Apache POI library?

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet 1");

Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("\uD83D\uDD25\uD83D\uDD25");

try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("text.xlsx");
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        workbook.close();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

As a result, I get a file with symbols "????" Instead of "".

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and improve your question.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38007641/write-16-bits-character-to-xlsx-file-using-apache-poi-in-java/38039869#38039869.