# Writing Unicode plane 1 characters with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, character-encoding, apache-poi

I'm trying to write Unicode characters into an Excel file. I did it successfully with Unicode plane 0, but not with Unicode plane 1.

I use POI 3.16 and use this simple piece of code to test :

```
    public void createFile() throws IOException {
        SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(1);
        SXSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("data");

        Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        String value = "ᚬᚬᚬ";
        cell.setCellValue(value);

        try (FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Emilien\\PROJECTS_FILES\\BUGS\\SLIMS_14124\\test.xlsx")) {
            workbook.write(fop);
        } finally {
            workbook.dispose();
        }
    }
```

In excel 2016, **the cell contains "??????ᚬᚬᚬ" instead of displaying "ᚬᚬᚬ"**.
Find URLs about characters here [ᚬ](http://graphemica.com/%E1%9A%AC) and here .

I unzipped the excel file and investigated the content of sheet *data*, the XML content corresponding to the cell is :

```
<row r="1">
   <c r="A1" t="inlineStr"><is><t>??????&#5804;&#5804;&#5804;</t></is></c> 
</row>
```

As we can see, the plane 0 characters have been converted into HTML Unicode characters, while the plane 1 characters have been lost.

If I change "??????" by "" in the XML file, and compress the files into a new xlsx file again, the characters are rendered as wanted (meaning, the cell actually contains  ᚬᚬᚬ).

It seems like the Java Strings are not written into the XML as UTF-8, but seem to be processed by POI (we end up with HTML characters). Has anyone experienced this before ? Is it possible to write SMP characters into an Excel file ?

Could it be a bug ? I mean, the XML files declare a UTF-8 encoding in their header but don't seem to respect it. Am I missing something ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38007641/write-16-bits-character-to-xlsx-file-using-apache-poi-in-java/38039869#38039869. This is a problem with `xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar `. Do using a newer version.

Comment: Hey. I tried to use xmlbeans-3.0.0 with POI 3.16 (by removing its 2.6.0 dependency) but it did not solve the issue. Then I tried POI 3.17 (still with 2.6.0) and it worked.

Comment: Seemed to be fixed in 3.17 indeed. http://mirror.easyname.ch/apache/poi/release/RELEASE-NOTES.txt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write 16 bits character to .xlsx file using Apache POI in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38007641/write-16-bits-character-to-xlsx-file-using-apache-poi-in-java)

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46239082/how-to-insert-emoji-in-excel-file-using-poi-xssf-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is different dependent of whether the streaming part  `SXSSF` of `apache poi` or the default `XSSF` part of `apache poi` is used.

[There was a problem with `xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38007641/write-16-bits-character-to-xlsx-file-using-apache-poi-in-java/38039869#38039869)  which `apache poi` until version `3.17` was using  for accessing `XML`. This library had excluded the high-surrogates range, (\uD800-\uDBFF) and the low-surrogates range (\uDC00-\uDFFF) of characters as "bad chars". That's why all Unicode which needs those surrogate ranges could not handled properly. That is the Unicode range from 0x10000 upwards. See [Supplementary Characters as Surrogates](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/supplementaryChars.html).

Then with `apache poi` version `3.17` this problem was worked around in their streaming `SXSSF` parts so that `SXSSF` had worked also using `xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar`. So the solution for the streaming `SXSSF` parts is simply updating to `apache poi`version `3.17`.

But the  `SXSSF` creates inline strings per default and works different than the `XSSF` part. That's why the `XSSF` further is creating wrong `XML` when Unicode above  0xFFFF is needed and `xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar` is used. For solving this in `XSSF` newer versions of XMLBeans are needed. There is `xmlbeans-2.6.2.jar` and now `xmlbeans-3.0.0.jar` available. Both are solving the problem with the `XSSF` part of `apache poi`.